# Is it possible to find the theoretical probability of getting an experimental probability equal to its theoretical probability?

Tags: probability

not sure if this makes sense, but I think it does.

If I were to roll 2 dice, the probability of having the same number on both would be 6 / 36.
Is it possible to find the theoretical probability of running 36,000 (for example) trials, and getting exactly 6000 double numbers?

Sorry if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sure.  You're describing a binomial random variable (with a value of $1$ for a pair, and $0$ otherwise).

Comment: $${n\choose k}\left(\frac16\right)^{k}\left(\frac56\right)^{n-k}\qquad n=36000\quad k=6000$$

Comment: @Adolfo No, the OP is interested in the probability of getting any number twice, which is 1/6.